# Question regarding expressing Fundamental Theorm of Calculus in Polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let's **consider a polynomial** in **$z$**;

$P_n(z)$=$(z-c_1)P_{n-1}(z)$; where $c_1$ is one of the $zeroes$ of the Polynomial $P_n(z)$.

.
.
.
.

$P_n(z)$=$(z-c_1)(z-c_2)P_{n-2}(z)$,$c_2$ is another root of $P_n(z)$.

Similarly by $Fundamental$ $Theorem$ $of$ $Algebra$.We know that Since $P_n(z)$ is a polynomial of nth degree , it will have $n$ roots

$P_n(z)=(z-c_1)(z-c_2)(z-c_3)...(z-c_n)$

Where $c_1,c_2,c_3,......,c_n$ are the roots of $Polynomial$ $P_n(z)$.

& $c_1,c_2,c_3...c_n \in \Bbb C$

Now in $Visual$ $Complex$ $ Analysis$ by $Tristan$ $Needham$ ,he converted the above linearization equation to ;

$P_n(z)=R_1R_2R_3..R_n e^{i(Φ_1+Φ_2+Φ_3+..+Φ_n)}$.

Now my problem with this is that ;

Let's say that $3+4i$ is one of the roots of $P_n(z)$ .
$\implies$ that $(z-(3+4i))$ is a factor of the the $Polynomial$ $P_n(z)$.

$A$ $side$ $note$ :

$z$= $3+4i$.

We know that $e^{iθ}$=$cos(θ)+isin(θ)$;

Writing $3+4i$ in polar form we get ;

$3+4i$=$5[cos(\tan^{-1}(4/3))+i sin(\tan^{-1}(4/3))]$

In exponential notation we can write it as ;

$3+4i$ = $5e^{i(tan^{-1}(4/3))}$

So $(z-5e^{itan^{-1}(4/3)})$ must be a factor.

So we can say that if $c_1$ is a root of the $Polynomial$ $P_n(z)$ then;
$(z-c_1)$ is the root .

If $R_1e^{iΦ_1}$ is a root then;

$(z-R_1e^{iΦ_1})$ is a factor then.

So the polynomial must be

$P_n(z)$=$(z-R_1e^{iΦ_1})(z-R_2e^{iΦ_2}).....(z-R_ne^{iΦ_n})$.

But how is the author writing this as $P_n(z)$=$R_1R_2R_3....R_n e^{i(Φ_1+Φ_2+Φ_3+...Φ_n)}$

Here $R$ refers to distance from origin and $Φ$ refers to the angle from $X$ axis from which the point lies along R.

[image: Necessary notes][image: Necessary notes 2]

Comment: This all depends on where/how $\,R_i, Φ_j\,$ are defined, which you did not quote.

Comment: @dxiv I have edited my Question as needed ,hope this conveys my question in a better way

Comment: If each $R_i$ and $\Phi_i$ is a number, then your quote from Needham is nonsense, since it makes $P_n(z)$ a number. So, what kind of objects are $R_i$ and $\Phi_i$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I am not sure that I have interpreted his explanation correctly ,I have attached the necessary pages for reference

Comment: OK, so, for any fixed complex number $z$, $R_i$ is the magnitude of $z-c_i$, and $\Phi_i$ is the argument of $z-c_i$ ––– **not** the magnitude and argument of $c_i$. So now it all makes perfect sense. Do you agree?

Comment: I think I get it ,but I haven't seen this kind of transformation anywhere ,I have seen converting a complex number to polar form (Euler's form) ,but expressing a factor in the form of $R_1e^{iΦ_1}$ ,seems a bit odd . Z is variable ,are  $R_i$ &$Φ_i$ variables too?

Comment: So ,let's say that $z=a_1+ib_1$,for that particular value of z ,when substituted in the polynomial we get different value of $R_1$ ,$Φ_1$ ..$R_2$,$ Φ_2$ ..etc; based on the value of$(z-c_1)$ & $(z-c_2)$  ..;on multiplying all those we get an output which is one of the values of the polynomial on its graph,$z=a_1+ib_1$ is the input and the we get the output by multiplying  ,similarly when $z=a_2+ib_2$ we substitute and multiply and get a different value output ,the main thing that I want to emphasize is that  values of $R_1$,$R_2$ ..;$Φ_1$,$Φ_2$ .changes for every $z$ value,(ie) for every input

Comment: @HarryCase Yes, $z$ is the "free variable" and $R_i, Φ_j$ are functions of $z$. From the context shown, this appears to be an attempt to explain $17^{th}$ century thinking using modern math, so it shouldn't be too surprising that it looks unfamiliar.

Comment: @dxiv ,ok got it ,thanks for the reply ,yeah you're right Needham's quote was ,this was an attempt to solve integrals of the form $\int \frac{dx}{x^n -1} $,like finding a general solution by Roger Cotes (I am not sure that this was his exact solution )

Comment: @dxiv ,but what problem does this transformation eliminate ?

Comment: @HarryCase I would guess that's explained in the pages that follow.